# How to set outlook PST read-only / set quota

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

Is there any way to 'lock' Outlook pst file?
My Users have hughe PSTs Id like to lock all historical files, backup and force users to create new once

In past it was enough to set R/O attribute - now Outlook doesnt work witch sych files

Comment: You can set a password when export the PST file.

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong - but I think passwords protects to open file. 
But Im looking way to 'lock' PST for edits only. So user should be able to read PST's content but not add anything more to it.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook cannot use and will not recognize a Read Only .PST file so you're only option is to password lock them or move them so that the users can't access them

Comment: But I want user to open and read this file, but nor change any content. Is this possiblw with passwd ?

Comment: No, it's like most other files, either full access or no access. I'm sure that there are other solutions to this issue, just not this one, the one you asked about and the first one that you tried. I would suggest seeing if you can do a little research on that and if/when you get stuck with another clear question, come back here and post it so we can help with it again to keep you moving forward

Comment: I did research and found really nothing...